# How to redirect URL with slash after domain url

Tags: url, hosting, redirect

I bought a domain on namecheap. I want to redirect that domain url to another url but, I don't want to redirect for example google.com > youtube.com . I want to redirect it with this slash after domain url like google.com/hello > youtube.com .. I can only redirect for example hello.google.com > youtube.com but not google.com/hello > youtube.com .. why I can't do that?

Comment: can you check this url https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-to-redirect-a-url-for-a-domain

Comment: i hope they will have a IT team for helping you since you have a paid version of namecheap